# redirectMatch in mod rewrite

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

We recently moved our web site to another server, say `http://newdomain.com`, while our old site is at say `http://olddomain.com`

I would like to keep the users directory on the old site accessible as it was before, that is `http://oldomain.com/~user`, but anything accessible under the root folder point to the new domain. The users directory on the old server are in the `/home/user` file system. So, I wrote following rules:

```
 RedirectMatch permanent ^/~(.*) /home/~$1

 RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1
```

while the second rule works flawlessly, the first one still wants to map to the new site as following: `http://newdomain.com/~user`.

How can I fix the two rules so that anything in `/var/www/html` on the old site redirects to the new site, but anything under `/home` does not redirect?

--

Here is the new code based on Ben's solution, which maps the urls for the access to users' home pages correctly, but the browser complains and does not show their sites. The root folder urls redirection works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
#   RewriteBase / -- I had to comment this as the apache did not like it
Rewriterule ^/~(.*) /~$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/~
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RewriteCond` to test if the URI prefix with `/home/~`, and use `RewriteRule` to rewrite the URL and make a permanent redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^~(.*) /home/~$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/~
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Line 3: if URI prefix with `~{any_characters}`, rewrite the URI to `/home/~{any_characters}`, redirect permanently

Line 5: Test if the URI not prefix with `/home/~{any_characters}`

Line 6: Then process the rewrite rule, rewrite the URI from `{any_characters}` to `http://newdomain.com/{any_characters}`, redirect permanently

Comment: Thanks @Ben. I had to make come changes to what you provided because the apache did not like the RewriteBase / in my default .conf file. Please see my updated code based on your solution in my question.

However, even though I can see the urls for the users home directory url stay same, such as http://olddomain.com/~user, the browser spits an error message: 

The page isn’t redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: where did you put the .htaccess file? is it root folder?

Comment: I have actually put these rules in the default config file located at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

I was having some problem with the .htaccess file not working in the root folder.

Comment: you should put it in the `DocumentRoot` folder, and set `AllowOverride FileInfo Options` in config file

Comment: Does putting rules in the .htaccess vs in the config files create any difference in behavior?

Comment: you must put `AllowOverride` in config file